# Navigating only one child widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app header and footer which I want to keep constant defined as:

[image: How I want it to swap between the middle widget]

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Column(
        children: [
        Container(child: Header()),
        Container(child: Page1()),
        Container(child: Footer()),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Page 1:

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Center(
           child: GestureDetector( 
               child: Text("String"),
               onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) =>Page2())))),
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use Navigator to push or pop the widgets. Previously, I would use switch case and a custom button for navigating between the pages, but the requirement is for using the back button/gesture on android so I have to use navigator. But when I use navigator the whole page changes to the Page2, and I lose the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your MainPage widget take a child parameter

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
final Widget child;

MainPage({this.child});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Column(
        children: [
        Container(child: Header()),
        Container(child: child),
        Container(child: Footer()),
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Center(
           child: GestureDetector( 
               child: Text("String"),
               onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => 
             MainPage(child: Page2()))))),
    }
}
```

This way you can pass in the current Page to be shown. This is the simplest way, but it doesn't get around the unnecessary rebuilding of the header and footer.

Another option would be to use something like a ValueListenableBuilder or Provider with ChangeNotifierProvider to rebuild only the middle area, depending on how complex you're willing to go.